# How can I tell what version of Delphi was used to create a project

Tags: delphi

If I have complete source code to a delphi project, how can I tell what version (i.e. Delphi 5, Delphi 7, Delphi 2010 etc) was used to create it, without opening it in Delphi?

I have a number of projects dating back to Delphi 6 era that I would like to categorise.  However I don't want to have to open each one in various versions of Delphi to figure out what version to use.

Comment: Just in case somebody stumbles on this question, here is one with some more extensive answers: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9757886/49925 and the Delphi Wiki page based on these answers: http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_find_out_which_Delphi_version_was_used_to_create_a_project%3F

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Delphi

project.dof

```
[FileVersion]
Version=7.0
```

#### BDS

project.dproj

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ProjectVersion>
      12.0
    </ProjectVersion>
```

<sub>this is stupid, this site doesnt support TAB in textarea!</sub>

Comment: Indeed, and trying to see if Shift+Tab or sth. like that worked, I accidentally posted a stupid answer.