# How do I determine the Delphi version which created a Delphi project

Tags: delphi

I am trying to automatically figure out which Delphi version (of Delphi 5 to XE2 installed on my computer) to use to open a given project without upgrading that project by mistake.

Up to Delphi 7 there is a .dof file in .ini format for each project.
Delphi 5 does not have any entry which might help, but starting from Delphi 6 there is a [FileVersion] section which contains the following values:

- Delphi 5: N/A
- Delphi 6: 6.0
- Delphi 7: 7.0

So I guess that settles that, since older Delphi versions do not concern me.

For Delphi 2005 and 2006 there is a .bdsproj file in XML format containing a version entry:
\BorlandProject\PersonalityInfo\Option\Option

In Delphi 2005 it looks like this:

`<Option Name="Version" Type="String">1.0</Option>`

In Delphi 2006 like this:

`<Option Name="Version">1.0</Option>`

So I could look whether the attribute "Type" exists and depending on that decide on Delphi 2005 or 2006.
Could somebody please have a look at his Delphi 2005 and 2006 projects and verify this difference? (Or do you maybe have got a better idea?)

**edit:** I just tried to verify this and found, that Delphi 2005 does not always add the Type-Attribute. So now I am stuck.

**edit:** Maybe the GUID stored there is unique to the Delphi version?

- Delphi 2005: {87D03616-A4C7-4B5A-AF0F-0164EA60BC59}
- Delphi 2006: {CFE1BEE6-6FDE-4241-8CA5-D38D14EAA768}

Somehow I doubt it, I am afraid that the GUID may represent different SKUs (Professional / Architect etc.). But maybe you could verify this?

Starting with Delphi 2007 there is a .dproj file in a different XML format. The Delphi 2007 format does not contain any version entry I could find, but from Delphi 2009 on there seems to be the following entry:

`\project\PropertyGroup\ProjectVersion`

These are the values I found in my .dproj files:

- Delphi 2007: N/A
- Delphi 2009: 12.0
- Delphi 2010: 12.0
- Delphi XE:   12.3
- Delphi XE2:  13.4

If these are correct, I could reliably determine Delphi 2007, XE and XE2. But how do I distinguish between Delphi 2009 and 2010?

Also, these numbers look odd to me. Does anybody know whether there are any differences between the various updates of Delphi, e.g. did the original Delphi XE2 release maybe start with 13.0 and with each update increment the number after the dot? But if that's the case, how did Delphi XE get 12.3?

(There is a similar question [How can I tell what version of Delphi was used to create a project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394136/how-can-i-tell-what-version-of-delphi-was-used-to-create-a-project) but the single answer there is quite limited.)

Just in case anybody else needs this: I have just added a [page to the Delphi Wiki](http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_find_out_which_Delphi_version_was_used_to_create_a_project%3F) which summarizes all answers and adds information for newer Delphi versions (currently up to Delphi 10.4.1).

Comment: Why do you need this? Surely you know which version of Delphi your projects are built with.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan see my answer below.

Comment: I'd suggest following a simple naming convention to clearly identify the target delphi version for a particular project file. E.g. We put our project files in a sub-folder. So the folder name indicates the Delphi version to be used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The version numbers in the *PROJ files are not bound to releases or updates and not all versions hit the streets.

- Delphi XE RTM used version 12.2
- Delphi XE Update #1 uses version 12.3
- Delphi XE2 (RTM till Update #4) uses 13.4

Answer (score 11):

I have now compared the .bdsproj files of Delphi 2005 and 2006 and there is no difference. Also, there is no difference between the .dproj files created by Delphi 2009 and 2010.

So the answer is:

- if a .dproj file exists -> read \project\PropertyGroup\ProjectVersion

  - empty -> Delphi 2007
  - 12.0 -> Delphi 2009 or 2010
  - 12.2 or 12.3 -> Delphi XE1 (according to Uwe Schuster)
  - 13.4 -> Delphi XE2
- if a .bdsproj file exists -> Delphi 2005 or 2006
- if a .dof file exists -> read [FileVersion]\version

  - empty -> Delphi 5 (or possibly older)
  - 6.0 -> Delphi 6
  - 7.0 -> Delphi 7

Unfortunately this does not allow me to write a program that automatically starts the correct Delphi version for a given project.

Maybe I will let the program ask the user if there are two possibilities and store his answer in a .ini file so the next time the program knows which Delphi version to start.

btw: The reason I was looking into this is that I have several times accidentally opened Delphi 2007 projects with a later Delphi version which upgraded it and I had to reverse these changes by hand. This has become so annoying that I wanted to prevent it by registering my own program as handler for .dpr files.

Comment: If you are reversing changes by hand then you need to use revision control

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: With "by hand" I meant clicking on the files and selecting Revert in TortoiseSVN. This is not as difficult as actually editing the files but still annoying. Btw: I have now solved the problem by adding a batch file to the project that opens it in the correct ide.

Comment: The unit search path may provide a hint about which compiler version the project was linked against.

Comment: This is the full answer.  I was going to create a launcher myself until I started adding a file to the project directory which signified which Delphi version to use.  I name the file Delphi<version>(and if only one platform: <platform>).txt  and keep a log inside of changes made to the project, among other things.  When/if you upgrade the project to a newer version of Delphi, rename this version controlled file so it's reflected in the history.

Comment: FWIW: There's by now a tool doing that: https://github.com/RRUZ/delphi-dev-shell-tools.

Answer (score 4):

Just installed XE3 (RTM).
14.3 XE3 (C++ & Delphi)

Comment: 14.4: XE4 and 15.1: XE5

Comment: 15.3: XE5 (Update 2); and 16.0: XE7

Answer (score 3):

Today I find this topic googlin about Delphi edition (Standard, Professional, Enterprise).

Anyway I checked some .dof files spread in mine machine and there is facts related to ancient delphi versions:

if a .dof file exists -> read [Directories]/Packages

Delphi 3

```
[Directories]
OutputDir=
UnitOutputDir=
SearchPath=
Packages=VCLX30;VCL30;INETDB30;INET30;
```

Delphi 5

```
[Directories]
OutputDir=.
UnitOutputDir=.
PackageDLLOutputDir=.
PackageDCPOutputDir=.
SearchPath=
Packages=Vcl50;Inet50;Inetdb50;Vclx50;Indy50;
```

Additional info can be finded near end of dof file:

D3:

```
[Excluded Packages]
C:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi 3\Bin\DCLDSS30.dpl=Delphi Decision Cube Components
C:\PROGRAM FILES\BORLAND\DELPHI 3\BIN\DCLTEE30.DPL=Delphi TeeChart Components
```

D5:

```
[Excluded Packages]
$(DELPHI)\Bin\CorIde50.bpl=Borland Core IDE Package
$(DELPHI)\Bin\direct50.bpl=Borland Direct IDE Package
```