# Collecting a list/table of version specific information for RAD Studio/Delphi/C++ Builder related development environments

Tags: delphi

I want to assemble a list of version related information on RAD Studio/Delphi/C++ Builder related development environments.

Rephrased (thanks [David M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/121689/david-m) for the [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18185156/collecting-a-list-table-of-version-specific-information-for-rad-studio-delphi-c?noredirect=1#comment26675384_18185156)) the question:

"What is the version-specific data for compilers Turbo Pascal 7 until Delphi XE4?"

Please use the following format when answering. You can put more than one version in an answer:

- Company Name
- Product Name
- Product Version
- Delphi Version
- BDS Version
- Platform targets supported
- `VERxxx` defines
- `__BORLANDC__` values
- `RTLVersion` values
- `CompilerVersion` versions
- `DllSuffix` Package Version (file suffixes of BPL and DCP files)
- `HKCU` base registry key
- `HKLM` base registry key
- Default base installation directories (on x86 and x64 systems)
- `ProjectVersion` value in `.dproj` files
- correlation between File Version and Update/Hotfix number
- primary link to on-line documentation
- Date of release
- Date of latest update/hotfix
- Codename

The question is: please provide as much of the above specific items as possible for each product.

I will help editing it into a more/less readable list.

Information of this kind is scattered around the internet, if available at all.

A comprehensive list like this makes it much easier for software developers to cross reference information between different Delphi versions.

Though I'm not limiting this list to other products (Turbo Pascal, Free Pascal, Lazarus, Kylix, C# Builder, Borland Pascal, Turbo Pascal for Windows, etc), my first goal is to get the Delphi list complete.

Though I know this is a bit of an open question, I think it is still warranted here at SO as it is:

- a quick way to reach a lot of knowledgeable people in this area of expertise
- allows contributors with high enough reputation to keep the Q&A thread clean

It is the reason I want to mark this question as a "Community Wiki": suited for historic material like this.
I will certainly try to keep this Q&A thread clean.

And I'm open to tips on how to make the list more "dense".

A few links I already found that are helpful:

- [Found a table with Delphi Conditional defines over the Delphi versions/compiler platforms/bitness](http://wiert.me/2013/02/20/someone-should-create-a-table-with-delphi-conditional-defines-over-the-delphi-versionscompiler-platformsbitness/)
- Answers in [What is the compiler version for Delphi 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369191/what-is-the-compiler-version-for-delphi-2010)
- [Compiler/RTL Version Overview](http://www.muetze1.de/?page_id=547)
- [Borland Compiler Conditional Defines](http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Borland_Compiler_Conditional_Defines)
- [Delphi Release Dates](http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Delphi_Release_Dates)
- [Delphi : History Box](http://www.dragonsoft.us/delphi_history.php)
- [Compiler Versions](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Compiler_Versions)
- [Predefined Macros](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Predefined_Macros)
- [Defines.inc](http://bo.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Native/Delphi/Include/Defines.inc) (I need to update this, but CodePlex SVN is broken right now)
- [jcl.inc](https://github.com/project-jedi/jcl/blob/master/jcl/source/include/jcl.inc), [jedi.inc](https://github.com/project-jedi/jedi/blob/master/jedi.inc) and [kylix.inc](https://github.com/project-jedi/jedi/blob/master/kylix.inc) from JEDI
- Two small programs to display versions: [Show__BORLANDC__ConsoleProject](https://bitbucket.org/jeroenp/besharp.net/src/c934acb55e9b6d714ba2f270d959d9b6bea6649d/Native/C++Builder/Apps/Console/Show__BORLANDC__ConsoleProject?at=default) and 
  [ShowDelphiVersionsConsoleProject](https://bitbucket.org/jeroenp/besharp.net/src/48a71f46e0e12dcaeff417056278f17bc59a6106/Native/Delphi/Apps/Console/ShowDelphiVersionsConsoleProject?at=default) to show `__BORLANDC__` in C++, and `VER###`, `CompilerVersion` and `RTLVersion` in Delphi.

As a starter, I'll answer for a few versions myself.
I will try making it community wiki answers so others can edit/complete them.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a question

Comment: @DavidHeffernan How should I make the motivation in the question more clear to make it a question?

Comment: It's not possible to make this a question. I find it hard to believe I'm saying this to a 15k user, but you should take a good read of the [faq]

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I know about the faq. I can make it 20+ different questions (one for each product) to adhere to the FAQ. So I'm trying to find a better way to get input for this. Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps the wiki could be updated to include all this information: http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Delphi_Release_Dates

Comment: My advice is to find a format and site that fits. And Q&A is not that format. If you do know the faq well, then how can you have asked this question. Did you just choose to ignore it?

Comment: @Tondrej I like the idea, there more love for non-Delphi info at http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Borland_Compiler_Release_Dates than the other one, see this edit: http://delphi.wikia.com/index.php?title=Delphi_Release_Dates&diff=1632&oldid=1484 Any idea about the format to put this in?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Part of the meta question is how to get this answered at all. I've bumped into lack of this information dozens of times, so I thought "lets bite the bullet and see if I can find cooperation".

Comment: SO is not a "let's make a list" site, and the [help] and [about] pages are both very clear about the types of posts that are proper for this site. "Because I feel like it's a good idea" is not a reason to violate those guidelines.

Comment: Shouldn't this be community wiki?  It's designed for those collaborative-answer questions. Closing just seems unhelpful.

Comment: @David SO is a Q&A site. There needs to be a question. You too should re-read the [faq].

Comment: @Jeroen: It's a great idea, if you do it in the appropriate place. SO isn't it.

Comment: @KenWhite  My original idea was to have one answer per Delphi version and make those community wiki style so people could contribute to them. Apparently there is a lot less love at SO for community-wiki answers than there was in the past. Any idea how to get the SO community involved to contribute for instance to a page at the wikia.com site like TOndrej suggested?

Comment: @Jeroen: Sorry; I have no idea. SO's guidelines are constantly evolving, and CW has been discouraged somewhat. Almost all of the [se] sites are strictly Q&A, and questions have to be on-topic according to the guidelines for that site.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I am sadly all too aware of how difficult it is to get certain sorts of information on SO, despite the community's willingness to help. But this is a question: "What is the version-specific data for compilers TP7-DXE4?"

Comment: @DavidM thanks for the tip. Rephrased it because of that. And fully reading the rephrased faq (which is not called [about](http://stackoverflow.com/about)) actually got me an [Informed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2600/informed?userid=29290) badge (:

Answer (score 7):

Part of the information comes from these sources:

- [How do I determine the Delphi version which created a Delphi project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9757886/how-do-i-determine-the-delphi-version-which-created-a-delphi-project)
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/radstudiodemos/ (note these are often incorrect: updates in various older branches have been done with newer Delphi versions)

## RAD Studio XE5

- Company Name
  *Embarcadero*
- Product Name
  *RAD Studio*
- Product Version
  *XE5*
- Delphi Version
  *19.0*
- BDS Version
  *12.0*
- Platform targets supported
  *Win32, Win64, OS X x86, iOS Arm, Android Arm*
- `VERxxx` defines
  *VER260*
- `__BORLANDC__` values
  *0x0670*
- `RTLVersion` values
  *26*
- `CompilerVersion` versions
  *26*
- `DllSuffix` Package Version (file suffixes of BPL and DCP files)
  *190*
- `HKCU` base registry key
  *HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\12.0*
- `HKLM` base registry key
  *N/A*
- Default base installation directories (on x86 and x64 systems)
  *x86: `C:\Program Files\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\12.0`*
  *x64: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\12.0`*
  *both: `C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0`*
- `ProjectVersion` value in `.dproj` files
  *15.1*
- correlation between File Version and Update/Hotfix number
  *19.0.13476.4176 =RTM*
- primary link to on-line documentation
  http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Main_Page
- Date of release
  *20130911*
- Date of latest update/hotfix
  *20130911 RTM*
- Codename
  *Zephyr*

## RAD Studio XE4

- Company Name
  *Embarcadero*
- Product Name
  *RAD Studio*
- Product Version
  *XE4*
- Delphi Version
  *18.0*
- BDS Version
  *11.0*
- Platform targets supported
  *Win32, Win64, OS X x86, iOS Arm*
- `VERxxx` defines
  *VER250*
- `__BORLANDC__` values
  *0x0660*
- `RTLVersion` values
  *25*
- `CompilerVersion` versions
  *25*
- `DllSuffix` Package Version (file suffixes of BPL and DCP files)
  *180*
- `HKCU` base registry key
  *HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\11.0*
- `HKLM` base registry key
  *N/A*
- Default base installation directories (on x86 and x64 systems)
  *x86: `C:\Program Files\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\11.0`*
  *x64: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\11.0`*
  *both: `C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\11.0`*
- `ProjectVersion` value in `.dproj` files
  *14.6*
- correlation between File Version and Update/Hotfix number
  *18.0.4905.60485=Update 1*
- primary link to on-line documentation
  http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/Main_Page
- Date of release
  *20130422*
- Date of latest update/hotfix
  *20130611 Update 1*
- Codename
  *Quintessence*

## RAD Studio XE3

- Company Name
  *Embarcadero*
- Product Name
  *RAD Studio*
- Product Version
  *XE3*
- Delphi Version
  *17.0*
- BDS Version
  *10.0*
- Platform targets supported
  *Win32, Win64, OS X x86*
- `VERxxx` defines
  *VER240*
- `__BORLANDC__` values
  [*0x0650 for C++Builder XE3 and XE3 Update 1*

  *0x0651 for January 2013 update (BCC32 and BCCOSX); BCC64 remained at 0x0650*](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Predefined_Macros#C.2B.2B_Compiler_Versions_in_Predefined_Macros)
- `RTLVersion` values
  *24*
- `CompilerVersion` versions
  *24*
- `DllSuffix` Package Version (file suffixes of BPL and DCP files)
  *170*
- `HKCU` base registry key
  *HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\10.0*
- `HKLM` base registry key
  *N/A*
- Default base installation directories (on x86 and x64 systems)
  *x86: `C:\Program Files\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\10.0`*
  *x64: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\10.0`*
  *both: `C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\10.0`*
- `ProjectVersion` value in `.dproj` files
  *14.3*
- correlation between File Version and Update/Hotfix number
  *17.0.4625.53395*
- primary link to on-line documentation
  http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/Main_Page
- Date of release
  *20120903*
- Date of latest update/hotfix
  *20130124 Update 2*
- Codename
  *Fulcrum*

## Delphi XE3

- `ProjectVersion` value in `.dproj` files
  *14.3* (RTM) *14.4* (Update 1)

## Delphi XE2

- `ProjectVersion` value in `.dproj` files
  *13.4*

## Delphi XE

- `ProjectVersion` value in `.dproj` files
  *12.3*, *12.2*

## Delphi 2010

- `ProjectVersion` value in `.dproj` files
  *12.0*

## Delphi 2009

- `ProjectVersion` value in `.dproj` files
  *11.1*, *12.0* (11.1 is probably from the beta stage, but the `demos` directory is full of them)

## Delphi 2007

- `ProjectVersion` value in `.dproj` files
  *N/A*

## Delphi 1

- Company Name
  *Borland*
- Product Name
  *Delphi*
- Product Version
  *1*
- Delphi Version
  *1.0*
- BDS Version
  *N/A*
- Platform targets supported
  *Win16, DOS??, DPMI??*
- `VERxxx` defines
  *VER80*
- `__BORLANDC__` values
  *N/A*
- `RTLVersion` values
  *N/A*
- `CompilerVersion` versions
  *N/A*
- `DllSuffix` Package Version (file suffixes of BPL and DCP files)
  *N/A*
- `HKCU` base registry key
  *N/A*
- `HKLM` base registry key
  *N/A*
- Default base installation directories (on x86 and x64 systems)
  *`C:\DELPHI`*
- `ProjectVersion` value in `.dproj` files
  *N/A*
- correlation between File Version and Update/Hotfix number
  *N/a*
- primary link to on-line documentation
  *N/A*
- Date of release
  *19950214*
- Date of latest update/hotfix
  *N/A*
- Codename
  *Wasabi, Mango, Delphi (original product name was supposed to be AppBuilder)*

## Borland Pascal 7

- Company Name
  *Borland*
- Product Name
  *Pascal*
- Product Version
  *7*
- Delphi Version
  *N/A*
- BDS Version
  *N/A*
- Platform targets supported
  *DOS, DPMI, Win16*
- `VERxxx` defines
  *VER70*
- `__BORLANDC__` values
  *N/A*
- `RTLVersion` values
  *N/A*
- `CompilerVersion` versions
  *N/A*
- `DllSuffix` Package Version (file suffixes of BPL and DCP files)
  *N/A*
- `HKCU` base registry key
  *N/A*
- `HKLM` base registry key
  *N/A*
- Default base installation directories (on x86 and x64 systems)
  *N/A*
- `ProjectVersion` value in `.dproj` files
  *N/A*
- correlation between File Version and Update/Hotfix number
  *7.01*
- primary link to on-line documentation
  *N/A*
- Date of release
  *19921027*
- Date of latest update/hotfix
  *N/A*
- Codename
  *N/A*

Comment: What is the point of this if it is so incomplete, out of date and unmaintained?

Comment: This kind of information should be moved to a page on the [Delphi Wikia](http://delphi.wikia.com) site, for instance.

Comment: I'm working to get the output of a table scripted into reStructuredText or Markdown. Would you guys be willing to help checking the output?